# 'Head over heels' - why?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The phrase 'Head over heels' is quite often used when someone falls over:

> He fell head over heels

But, in my mind it doesn't make much sense. If your head is over your heels (feet) then you're standing upright and not falling over at all.

So, where did the phrase come from ?

*There is another, ruder version - 'Arse over tit' which actually does make sense.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Emerged in the 14th century as "heels over head", which is more literally accurate, as "head over heels" is the more standard state of being. "Heels over head" evolved into "head over heels" in common use departing its literal meaning, probably for reasons of phrasal elegance

[Source](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/head_over_heels)